# Можно ли заменить Promise.all на async await?

Tags: javascript, frontend, async-await, promise

Есть массив функций 'arr', которые возвращают промисы, нужно что бы запросы в этих функциях выполнялись параллельно, и когда все функции выполнятся, обработать результат их работы, самое логичное, это кончено `Promise.all(arr).then((data) => { обработка результата })`

**Но мне стало любопытно, можно ли добиться такого же эффетка но без Promise.all, а использую только async await при работе с массивом 'arr' ?**

Comment: Параллельно на однопоточном js вы в это верите?

Comment: Возможно только вот зачем?

Comment: Пожалуйста неипутайте асинхронный вызов с какой-то парралельностью

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это эквиваленты:

```js
const arr = [
 () => Promise.resolve(1),
 () => Promise.resolve(2),
 () => Promise.resolve(3),
];

Promise.all(arr.map(f => f()))
  .then((data) => { console.log(data); });
```

```js
const arr = [
 () => Promise.resolve(1),
 () => Promise.resolve(2),
 () => Promise.resolve(3),
];

(async function main() {
  const data = [];
  for await (const result of arr.map(f => f())) {
    data.push(result);
  }
  console.log(data);
})();
```